# wp_nav_menu - add class on UL

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, wp-nav-walker, wp-nav-menu-item

I am learning `wordpress` together with `bootstrap` and somehow I can't add `class` on `UL` tag.

In the screenshot, I want to add class `nav nav-tabs` on `UL` but it was added on parent `div`

```php
$defaults = array(
  'menu_class'=> 'nav nav-tabs',        
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

Inspected element:

[image]

Referrence:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Comment: Please post all the parameters you pass to `wp_nav_menu`.

Comment: This is what I created in BEM notation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847953/wordpress-primary-navigation-ul-li-class-override

Comment: You will want to make sure that you've set up a custom menu selecting the menu location as top menu. The default Wordpress menu will not work and you will get the problem you're having.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First of all, you need to create a custom navigation menu from `Appearance -> Menus`.

Then, use the `wp_nav_menu` with the following parameters:

```
<?php 
$args = array(
    'menu_class' => 'nav nav-tabs',        
    'menu' => '(your_menu_id)'
);
wp_nav_menu( $args ); 
?>
```

There's a lot you can read about Wordpress Menus. I suggest the following:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus
http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-register-menus-in-wordpress

Comment: It seems it doesn't work. My parameter in my post is the only parameter I specified.

Comment: Do you have menus defined in your wordpress dashboard? http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel

Comment: Nope, just the default one. It seems it is still the same.

Comment: Well, if you don't have menus, `wp_nav_menu` will display the output of `wp_page_menu` function, which displays all the pages. Try to create a menu and then use the `menu` parameter.

Comment: Look on my way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59847953/wordpress-primary-navigation-ul-li-class-override

Answer (score 25):

You need to specify the container element, in our case `'ul'` tag, and than specify the class that we will assign in `'menu_class'`. Here is the sample code:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'top-menu',
    'container' => 'ul',
    'menu_class'=> '[add-your-class-here]'
 ) );
```

Comment: now everything makes sense.

Answer (score 7):

Update: this was caused by the fact that i didn't have a menu created in the menu page.

I want to add a class to the `ul` of `wp_nav_menu`. I tried this code:

```
<?php

$defaults = array(
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

According to wordpress codex changing the menu from `'menu_class' => 'menu'`, should change the class of the `ul`, but instead it changes the class of the `div` wrapping the `ul`.

  [Sample Page](http://domain.tld/)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, so I changed the word "theme_location" to "name" and it works perfectly.

Example:

```
$defaults = array(
    '[INSTEAD OF PUTTING "theme_location" PUT "name"]'  => 'THE NAME OF YOUR "theme_location"',
    'menu_class' => 'YOUR CLASS', **[It will change the <UL> class]**
    );

    wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

So for your code:

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
    'name' => 'top-menu',
    'menu_class'=> 'YOUR CLASS'
 ) );

 wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBva9.png)

You can also put it into a container like a <DIV> or a <NAV> etc.

Example:

```
$defaults = array(
    'name'  => 'top-menu',
    'menu_id'         => 'YOUR ID',
    'container'       => 'nav',
    'container_class' => 'YOUR CONTAINER CLASS (<nav> in this case)',
    'menu_class'      => 'YOUR CLASS FOR <UL>',
    );

    wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeCsj.png)

Comment: Why does `name` work perfectly..yet its not documented anywhere in the codex? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/

Answer (score 2):

This is how you should do it, it works for me.

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( $menu_meta );

$menu_meta = array(
    'menu' => 'MENU-NAME-HERE',
    'items_wrap' => '<ul id="MENU-ID" class="MENU-CLASS">%3$s</ul>'
); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this. It works for me

```
     wp_nav_menu( array(
    'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
    'container' => 'ul',
    'menu_class'=> '[your-class-here]'
 ) );
```